# EDITED: My code does not work the catch block during exception handling

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

**EDITED**

I have changed my code a bit, I have the following function in my page object.

```
public void kenshoSearch(String searchTerm) throws Exception
{
    driver.findElement(kenshoSearchBox).sendKeys(searchTerm);
    try {
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(kenshoSearchVerify));
    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        System.out.println("No Results Found");
    }   
}
```

When I run a test for the keyword that does not have any results, it should print out "No Results Found" but in actual it throws NoSuchElementException on console along with stack trace.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

There are actually two ways:

1.) 
You can catch the `NoSuchElementException` and throw a new `AssertException` with your text message.

2.) 
Instead of catching the exception you should use:

```
List<WebElement> elements = getDriver().findElements(By.xpath("your xpath"));
Assert.assertTrue(elements.size()>0, "No Results found for \"Search Term\" ");
```

Here you try to fill a list with all found elements by using `findElements` instead of `findElement`. If `findElements` doesn't find any `WebElement` it doesn't throw an exception. So you can easilly check by the size of list if a element was found.

Comment: #2 is the better way...you can also use `!elements.isEmpty()` instead of `elements.size() > 0`

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your code in a try...catch block and handle the assertion after you caught the NoSuchElementException:

```
try {    
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated("xpath of the div that contains the results"));
} catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
    // ...
}
```